# is it possible to use the same app ID for multiple applications?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, app-store

I was wondering if it's possible to use the same app ID for multiple iOS applications. Apologize if this is a really simple question, but I just could not find it anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You can create a wildcard app ID which might be what you're thinking of so that you've just got one provisioning profile for a suite of apps. See the [Apple docs on it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ApplicationDevelopmentOverview/ConfigureYourProject/ConfigureYourProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011186-CH6-SW8).

Comment: so i guess I'd just create a unique ID for each app just to be on the a safe side? (who knows, one day I may add IAP and then will need to switch from the wildcard to a unique one...)

Comment: You can do the switch, though. I've done it for 2 apps and it works fine. IMHO, create a wildcard and then if you need to later, then switch.

Answer (score 1):

pretty sure they're unique.. that's how the OS uniquely identifies your app no matter what your bundle is named etc.

From the documentation:

> CFBundleIdentifier
>
> CFBundleIdentifier (String - iOS, Mac OS X) uniquely identifies the
>   bundle. Each distinct application or bundle on the system must have a
>   unique bundle ID. The system uses this string to identify your
>   application in many ways. For example, the preferences system uses
>   this string to identify the application for which a given preference
>   applies; Launch Services uses the bundle identifier to locate an
>   application capable of opening a particular file, using the first
>   application it finds with the given identifier; in iOS, the bundle
>   identifier is used in validating the application’s signature.
>
> The bundle ID string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that
>   contains only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.)
>   characters. The string should also be in reverse-DNS format. For
>   example, if your company’s domain is Ajax.com and you create an
>   application named Hello, you could assign the string com.Ajax.Hello as
>   your application’s bundle identifier.

Comment: You can try this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102070